# What state is a sleeping thread in?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm looking for verification/arguments on the following:

A thread is in exactly one of the 5 (+1 -- 2 for `WAITING`) [states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) at any point of time.

Suppose a thread `T` calls

> Thread.sleep(3000);

and thus puts itself into sleep for 3 secs.

Which state is it in during those 3 secs?

It's clearly `start()`-ed and is still alive, thus is neither `NEW` nor `TERMINATED`.

It isn't waiting on any lock. in fact, it hasn't released any of the locks it had just before this call, so it isn't `BLOCKED`.

It's not waiting on another thread. Is waiting on itself in some sense-- but that's not the specification of the `WAITING` state. What gets a thread into a `WAITING` state is one of the calls: `Object.wait()`, `Thread.join()` and `LockSupport.park()`.

So it should be `RUNNABLE` -- the only one left out among the thread states. 
However, `RUNNABLE` is the state a thread is executing on JVM-- is enabled for CPU time and thus for burning resources. 
A sleeping thread being on CPU schedule seems contradictory.

Am i missing anything here?

TIA.

Comment: It's blocked, it's waiting for the OS to wake it for I/O.

Comment: Re "RUNNABLE is the state a thread is executing on JVM", True when you're talking about the Java library's Thread.getState(), but just in case you're interested; in the nomenclature of many operating systems, "runnable" means that the thread is _not_ "running" because it is waiting for an available CPU to run on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Javadoc of Thead.State.TIMED_WAITING [reads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TIMED_WAITING):

> Thread state for a waiting thread with a specified waiting time. A thread is in the timed waiting state due to calling one of the following methods with a specified positive waiting time:
>
> - `Thread.sleep`
> - `Object.wait` with timeout
> - `Thread.join` with timeout
> - `LockSupport.parkNanos`
> - `LockSupport.parkUntil`

And indeed, the following test program prints TIMED_WAITING:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
        };
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(100); // make sure the other thread has started
        System.out.println(t.getState());
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for the useful ans. read WAITING only- passed on TIMED_WAITING all along.

Comment: exactly similar thing happened with me and it got me here at this question.

Answer (score -1):

My code shows both TIMED_WAITING AND RUNNABLE thread states. Below are classes SimpleThread.java and Concurrent.java. Compile at the command line with, javac Concurrent.java SimpleThread.java. Run with, java Concurrent

#### SimpleThread.java

```
class SimpleThread extends Thread {
    
    private int id;
    
    // class constructor
    public SimpleThread(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    // function to be executed by thread
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread " + id + " is running.");
        System.out.println("t" + id + " thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        
        // interrupt the thread for 2 second (2000 ms)
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("t" + id + " tick - " + i);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("t" + id + " " + this.getState());
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Thread " + id + " is sleeping.");
        }
        
        System.out.println("Thread " + id + " execution is complete.");
    }
}
```

#### Concurrent.java

```
class Concurrent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        SimpleThread t1 = new SimpleThread(1);
        SimpleThread t2 = new SimpleThread(2);
        
        // thread state before it is started
        System.out.println("t1 thread state: " + t1.getState());
        System.out.println("t2 thread state: " + t2.getState());
        
        // execute thread run method
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        
        // put t1 to sleep for 1 second
        try {
            t1.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("t1 thread state " + t1.getState());
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        // finish all threads before returning to the main thread.
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();      
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        System.out.println("t1 thread state: " + t1.getState());
        System.out.println("t2 thread state: " + t2.getState());
    }
}
```

#### Program Output

```
1 thread state: NEW
t2 thread state: NEW
Thread 1 is running.
Thread 2 is running.
t2 thread name: Thread-1
t1 thread name: Thread-0
t2 tick - 0
t1 tick - 0
t1 thread state TIMED_WAITING
t1 RUNNABLE
t1 tick - 1
t2 RUNNABLE
t2 tick - 1
t1 RUNNABLE
t1 tick - 2
t2 RUNNABLE
t2 tick - 2
t1 RUNNABLE
t2 RUNNABLE
Thread 1 execution is complete.
Thread 2 execution is complete.
t1 thread state: TERMINATED
t2 thread state: TERMINATED
```

Comment: You are misleading yourself.  Some of the getState calls on t1 are being made by the thread itself.  Those calls will happen when the thread is running and they will show RUNNABLE ... obviously.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).